# Tracking root domain and subdomains in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

Thanks in advance for helping.
Here what i'm trying to do:

Let's say i have these 3 sites:

```
example.com     = US
ca.example.com  = Canada
fr.example.com  = France
```

1- I want to see traffic from ca.example.com and fr.example.com in example.com
2- But when i'm in ca.example.com i only want to see traffic from ca.example.com, same for fr.example.com

Here what i already tried:

All 3 sites have the same GA code. 
I created 3 views and applied advanced filter on each of them.

Create New Filter > Custom > Advanced

```
Field A > Hostname = (.*)
Field B > Request URI = (.*)
Output > Request URI = $A1$B1
```

After i excluded example.com on the two subdomains

I don't know if this is the right method. When i visit any of the site, i always see the visit of all 3 views.

Hope this is details enough.
Regards,

Comment: Please take the [tour] and follow up with your post. "Thanks" comments are discouraged. Use voting instead, and accept the best answer that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not wrong, you need to exclude traffic to hostnames for two views.

The "fr.example.com" view (predifined) filters can be:

- "exlude" + "traffic to the hostame" + "that are equal to" + "example.com"
- "exlude" + "traffic to the hostame" + "that are equal to" + "ca.example.com"

The "ca.example.com" view (predifined) filters can be:

- "exlude" + "traffic to the hostame" + "that are equal to" + "example.com"
- "exlude" + "traffic to the hostame" + "that are equal to" + "fr.example.com"

The "example.com" view filters can be:

- left as it, all traffic to every hostnames will be collected into this view